# Handling Multiple Subscription in GooglePlay

Tags: in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, subscription, android-developer-api, purchase-order

In ios and amazon - we have a subscription family - example if i have purchased a one month subscription, I cannot purchase a six month subscription of the same family. But it appears that this is not the case in google play. For example a user might have a monthly subscription running with a one year subscription also running simultaneously.

Do we have to handle the logic of not allowing a user to purchase a second subscription if he has already subscribed to one subscription?

Answer (score 5):

In iOS the user can change duration for the same subscription family though their iTunes subscription management page. On android you must implement this in the app using the `getBuyIntentToReplaceSkus()` method:

> This method is used to upgrade or downgrade a subscription purchase. The method is similar to `getBuyIntent()`, except that it takes a list of already-purchased SKUs that are to be replaced with the SKU being purchased. When the user completes the purchase, Google Play cancels the old SKUs and credits the user with the unused value of their subscription time on a pro-rated basis. Google Play applies this credit to the new subscription, and does not begin billing the user for the new subscription until after the credit is used up.

http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html#upgrade-getBuyIntentToReplaceSkus